# ImageMagick fixed height, proportional width in PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick

Before this gets shot down as low-effort, I did search the PHP documentation, spent fair amount on google and closest I came to is `set Image Geometry`, but this function is not in PHP documentation. I need to force the image height to be fixed 120px and proportional width after upload for photogallery thumbnails. Is there a way to do it?

I tried

```
$imgMagick->resizeImage(0, 120,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,0, TRUE);
```

but that obviously does not work

Comment: Sure, basic maths. Work out the proportion of the fixed height to the original height, and apply the same proportion change to the width. E.g. if the original height was 300px and width 100px, the fixed height is half (300 * 0.5) the original height. Apply the same to the width, (100 * 0.5) which would be 50px.

Comment: You probably want to check your Imagick version as options have changed at least twice according to the php documentation. You could also do some calculations as Jon suggests; I would use GD's getimagesize for the dimensions. This is why I use Imagemagick with exec( ). Anyway you are using Imagick and not Imagemagick directly so you should change your thread tag from Imagemagick to Imagick

Comment: Why doesn't your command work - it looks fine to me.